Sum of powers of distances between points in concentric circles
Let we have two concentric circles.

Inner circle contains one point and outer circle - $N$ points as regular polygon vertices.
It is well known that the sum of the squares of the distances from any point of one of them to the endpoints of any diameter of the other, is a fixed quantity.
But with interactive engine I see that total of all squared distances from inner point to outer points is constant (with given radii).
How to prove it?
The total of Euclidean distances depends on the position of the point, but very weak.
Sums of other powers ($-2,-1,3,4$) also variate, more or less.
Is it possible to analyse it's behaviour?
UPD
For this beautiful tetra-pentagram (with radii $1$ and $0.5$)

I've found numerically that sum of pair-wise Euclidean distances variate  near $21.270888$ with error less than $10^{-7}$ (but not constant!)

You can solve this through complex coordinates.
I will choose the center of the circles to be 0.
The the regular polynomial is given by $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N$.
And the point $P$ has a fixed distance from the origin.
The vectors between the point $P$ and $a_i$ has length $||P-a_i||^2 = ||P||^2 - a_i\overline{P}-\overline{a_i}P+ ||a_i||^2$.
Summing this over every point in the regular polynomial gives
$N ||P||^2 - \sum_i a_i\overline{P} - \sum_i \overline{a_i}P + \sum_i ||a_i||^2$.
But we know that the sum of $a_i$ is $0$, because that is the center of the circles. The length of $a_i$ is also known and given by the radius of the larger circle.
So the quantity you've described is given by $N ||P||^2 + N ||a_0||^2$.
This only depends on the number of points and the radii of the circles.
Nicely spotted invariant!

So $a_i$ could be any points in outer circle, not only regular poly vertices?

They need to have a center of mass equal to the center. (i.e. the sum should be zero.)

Thank you, I see!
Interestingly  is it possible to estimate somehow deviation/bounds for sums of other powers?

You can use this method to calculate these quantities explicitly, but the calculations get a lot messier. For odd powers the quantity $||P-a_i||^n$ is not even a polynomial expression in terms of $P, a_i, \overline{P}, \overline{a_i}$.

So the only thing special about the set of points $a_i$ is that its barycenter is the origin -they don't even need to lie on a circle.

@arkeet correct.

Sums of other powers

Sums of other powers (−2,−1,3,4) also variate, more or less.
Is it possible to analyse it's behaviour?

A partial answer: for positive powers $2d$, the sum of distances to that power is invariant if $d < N$.
This may be seen by extending jMdA's approach of complex coordinates. By scaling and rotation, we can assume wlog that the polygon's vertices are the $N^\textrm{th}$ roots of unity, $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_N$. Let $P$ be a point on a circle about the origin of given radius $R$, i.e. $||P||=R$.
The distances between the point $P$ and $z_i$ each contribute
\begin{align}
||P-z_i||^{2d} &= (||P||^2 - z_i\overline{P}-\overline{z_i}P+ ||z_i||^2)^d \\
%&=((R+1) - (z_i \bar P + \bar z_i P))^d \\
%&=\sum_{k=0}^d {d\choose k}(R+1)^{k-i}(-1)^k(z_i \bar P + \bar z_i P)^k.
\end{align}
Now $P \bar P=||P||=R$ and $z_i \bar z_i=||z_i||=1$ are constants, so after fully expanding and simplifying conjugate pairs, all non-constant terms may be expressed as a constant times $z_i^k \bar P^k$ (or its conjugate), where $1\le k\le d$.
When summing termwise over all $N$ roots, those non-constant terms have form $\bar P^k \sum_{i=1}^N z_i^k$ (or conjugate). But since $1<k\le d<N$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^N z_i^k=0$ and these terms are all zero. (Raising to a power smaller than $N$ maps the $N^\textrm{th}$ roots of unity either to itself or to a multiple of the $M^\textrm{th}$ roots of unity for some $2\le M< N$; either way the sum of these roots is zero. In contrast, if $k$ is a multiple of $N$, then $z_i^k=1$ and the sum is nonzero.)
Sum of squared distances in higher dimensions
For any set of points in any dimension: the sum of squared distances to point $P$ depends only on the distance from $P$ to the points' centroid.
We can see this by applying jMdA's approach but using vectors (of arbitrary dimension) instead of complex coordinates.
Let $V$ be a set of $N$ points. For simplicity, set the origin at the points' centroid, i.e., $\sum_{v\in V} v=0$. Let $P$ be any other point (i.e. on a hyper sphere of radius $||P||$centered at the origin.) Each point $v$ contributes squared distance
$$||P-v||^2 = (P-v)^T(P-v)
=||P||^2 - P^T v - v^T P + ||v||^2 .$$
Summing this over every point in $V$ gives
$$N ||P||^2 - 2 P^T\sum_{v\in V}v + \sum_{v\in V}||v||^2$$
The sum in the middle term is zero, and the remaining terms are constant with respect to $P$ on the hyper sphere. Thus we have shown the sum of the squared distances remains constant, for points in any dimension.
Application to springs
This invariant has an interesting physical implication for springs. Recall that a spring which is stretched distance $x$ from rest has potential energy  proportional to $x^2$.
Suppose $P$ is attached to each point $v\in V$ by identical springs. Then the total potential energy stored in the springs is proportional to the sum of the squared distances to each $v$. (Assuming ideal springs which are infinitesimally short at rest)
As calculated above, this sum varies according to $||P||^2$, the distance of $P$ to the centroid. But this is (up to a constant) the same potential energy we would see if $P$ were instead attached to the centroid by a single spring. This means $P$ behaves as if it is attached by a single spring to the centroid!

Thank you very much! I'm still work with this problem, and your ideas very close to what i'm found. I'm going to reformulate this question on Physics SE, so it's very close to potential field theory. Please check link (in this post as upd) a bit later
